# Proper way to get the value of a repeated annotation?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Java 8 introduced [repeating annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html), but had to shoehorn them in over the existing structure which didn't directly support them. They did this by introducing a `@Repeatable` meta-annotation but you get different behavior depending on whether there's one or more-than-one annotation on an object:

> **If more than one annotation of the requested type is present**, you can obtain them by first getting their container annotation.

This implies that if only one annotation is present you *can't* use the container annotation, and lo-and-behold that appears to be the case. I wrote the following to handle the one and more-than-one cases together, but it seems overly-complex:

```
public static <C, T> List<T> getAnnotations(
    Method m, Class<C> containerClass, Class<T> annotationClass) {
  C container = m.getAnnotation(containerClass);
  if (container != null && container.value().length > 0) {
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(container.value());
  }
  // apparently the @Container isn't considered set unless
  // there's *repeated* @Annotation elements
  T annotation = m.getAnnotation(annotationClass);
  if (annotation != null) {
    return ImmutableList.of(annotation);
  }
  return ImmutableList.of();
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to go about this? The docs also mention using [`AnnotatedElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html) but I don't see how to use this; the methods only seem to take `Class` objects, not `Method` or `Field` objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "Retrieving Annotations" section of the doc doesn't do a great job of describing the proper way to retrieve repeated annotations. They mention `.getAnnotationByType()` as useful for legacy code, and a `getAnnotations(Class<T>)` method that [doesn't exist](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170570).

The missing method had initially confused me so I stuck with the legacy behavior (hence the helper method), but the right method appears to be [`.getAnnotationsByType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getAnnotationsByType-java.lang.Class-) which handles both cases (and as a bonus never returns `null`), so you can simply say:

```
yourMethod.getAnnotationsByType(YourRepeatableAnnotation.class)
```

to get all the `@YourRepeatableAnnotation` annotations on `yourMethod`, or an empty array if the method isn't annotated.